# Arrow For Indication of Child Theme

Tags: css, indicator

I want to create a menu using CSS, and i want to differentiate when a parent has a child theme present that it shows a custom picture (i.e. an arrow of some form) to show this.

I know that this can be done via a suckerfish or superfish menu, however this is something that i haven't got my head round yet.

Can this be done in CSS by specifying an indicator when child theme present?

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of menu markup are you using? If it’s just nested `ul` elements, it sounds like you just need `list-style-image`, but is this interpretation too simple?

Comment: well ive seen for example a suckerfish menu... and it used an .sf-sub-indicator for the presence of a child theme... is that something that can be done? As i just want to apply it to all options where there is a child theme present